# Collecting and viewing statistical data on website usage? Want to give Google Analytics the boot

Tags: piwik

I have always been somewhat reluctant to "outsource" site statistics to Google.

We have an Apache server running on a Windows server. I am pretty sure all the foundation to collect the needed visitor data are there.

I would like to stop using GA, and use some form of application where the data does not travel to a third party but remains at the host, or at least travels to the remote administrator, if it is a log analyzer in a browser.

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite a fan of using the Open Source Web Analytics package [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) we have a large number of internal sites that we like hold statistics on and Piwik produces many of the same reports as Google Analytics.

The backed requires PHP and MySQL however the tracking code only requires JavaScript (similar to GA), in my case a IIS Website on one of my PHP Enabled 1VCPU, 1GB Virtual Machines works well for about 30 websites, 2500 users, and about half a million hits per day.

The project seems to be undergoing constant development and evolution, the developers appear to have a [clear vision for the future](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/Piwik-Vision-Roadmap). Not had any experience with support as it hasn't gone wrong yet.